# hapi: Do not get CORS header

Tags: node.js, hapi

I am using hapi 20.2.1

Here is how I create a server

```
 const Hapi = require("@hapi/hapi")
 const routes = require("./routes")

 const init = async () => {
    const server = Hapi.server({
      port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
      debug: { request: ["error"] },
      routes: {
        cors: true,
      },
    })
    ....set auth....
    routes(server)
    await server.start()
}

init()
```

When I see the response headers on routes, I am expecting `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'`. However, I do not see this header at all.

What am I probably doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

For the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to appear in the response header, you need to send the `Origin` header in the request header. Ideally, the value of the `Origin` header would be the origin of the UI that is making the cross-origin call.

In the request header, if you send an `Origin` value that is not allowed, then the Hapi server would not send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response, thus browser will block the reponse.